# -lstdc++ to LIBADD option stripped in libtool archive

Tags: linker, dynamic-linking, automake, libtool

I'm working on a C code but need to couple with a C++ code. My Makefile.am has lines like

```
libfoo_la_LIBADD += -lstdc++
```

but the generated libtool archive libmhd.la does not have -lstdc++ in the dependency_libs, and at linking time errors like "undefined references" to stdc++ symbols flush my screen. I tried to add -lstdc++ to libfoo_la_LDFLAGS, also tried "make LDFLAGS=-lstdc++" but neither helped.

I read from the [libstdc++ mail list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2010-01/msg00037.html) that -lstdc++ is removed from libtool postdeps for CXX. How can I manually force it either in the Makefile.am or at command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out if I append the -lstdc++ option to the final **executable**'s LDADD, i.e. `myexe_LDADD = -lstdc++ $(LDADD)`, then it works. To generate the .la file, libtool does not need to link to libstdc++ (yet), thus the -lstdc++ option is removed.